# Position a div in middle of another div without success

Tags: html

```html
<html>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        .tb_input {
            display: table-cell;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 100% !important;
        }
    </style>

    <div style="display: table; width: 100%">
        <div style="display:table-cell;border:1px solid;width: 50%;height: 100vh">
            <div style="display: block; width: 368px; padding: 40px 0px 60px 0px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
                <div style="width: 368px; display: block; background: #f4f4f4">
                    <div style="display: block; padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px">Email</div>
                        <div style="display: block; padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px">
                            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$Email" type="email" id="MainContent_Email" class="tb_input" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="display: block; width:300px;position: absolute;bottom: 0;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto ">
                    <p style=" width: 200px;">footer</p>
                </div>
            </div>
           <div style="width: 50%;">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The HTML code above split the whole space to left and right, I put the things in left side. The only problem now is the footer does not go in the middle of left side. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set **relative** positioning for the parent `div` when the child is **absolute**. Also, you missed rules `right: 0` and `bottom: 0` for an **absolute** block ... etc.

Also, I set `text-align: center`, `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` for tag `<p>`.

Just use this.

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <style type="text/css">
            .tb_input {
                display: table-cell;
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 100% !important;
            }
        </style>

        <div style="display: table; width: 100%;">
            <div style="display: table-cell; border: 1px solid; width: 50%; height: 100vh; position: relative;">
                <div style="display: block; width: 368px; padding: 40px 0px 60px 0px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                    <div style="width: 368px; display: block; background: #f4f4f4;">
                        <div style="display: block; padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px;">Email</div>
                        <div style="display: block; padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;">
                            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$Email" type="email" id="MainContent_Email" class="tb_input" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="display: block; width: 100%; position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;">
                    <p style="width: 200px; text-align: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">footer</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 50%;"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain _what_ and _why_ you changed it. No one can learn from your current answer.